# NSMangedObjectContext performBlock in background issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, dispatch-async

I read this [article](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) to save objects in Core Data database in background.

In the end of the article they have this code to save data in background:

```
[temporaryContext performBlock:^{
   // do something that takes some time asynchronously using the temp context
```

I understand that if we use `performBlock` the operation will be done asynchronously, but in what queue? Do I need to put it in background thread like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
            temporaryContext.performBlock({ () -> Void in

            })
        })
```

or it's enough to use:

```
temporaryContext.performBlock({ () -> Void in

                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to use:

```
temporaryContext.performBlock({ () -> Void in

})
```

Your code will be invoked in a queue associated with a temporaryContext. The temporaryContext is a NSManagedObjectContext which has its own private queue (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType)